# Validate a Domain Name with Javascript in Real Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, dns

I have a simple one-field form that asks for a domain name:

```
<form name="domainForm" action="result.html" >
http://<input type="text" size="10" name="domain_name" id="domain_name">
<a href="javascript: validateDomain(domainForm);">Submit</a>
</form>
```

... and validates using a JS function:

```
<Script type="text/javascript">

  function validateDomain(the_form)
  {   
    var the_domain = the_form.domain_name.value;

    // strip off "http://" and/or "www."
    the_domain = the_domain.replace("http://","");
    the_domain = the_domain.replace("www.","");

    var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
    if ( reg.test(the_domain) == false) 
    {
      alert( "Please Enter a Valid Domain Name" );
      the_form.domain_name.focus();
      return false;
    } // end if
  } // end validateDomain()
</script>
```

However, it'd be nice to validate in real time. As an aside, I'd really like to conceal the variables in a POST method instead of GET but AFAIK one must use GET when validating with JavaScript.

Any input/advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why doesn't your code work in real time? Do you mean you want it to test whether the web site is alive?

Comment: use onchange method on the input

Comment: The best way to validate a domain would be to `GET` the page and check the status

Comment: Clarification: looking to update the field after input and/or a certain amount of time. I know this is difficult to do because there's only one field. Also, onchange won't work because it relies on the user leaving the field - see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use keypress event on the input display the results in a `p`

```js
$("#domain_name").on('keypress', function() {
  var the_domain = $(this).val();

  // strip off "http://" and/or "www."
  the_domain = the_domain.replace("http://", "");
  the_domain = the_domain.replace("www.", "");

  var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
  if (reg.test(the_domain) == false) {

    $('#domain_name').focus();
    $('.rez').text('Please Enter a Valid Domain Name');
  } else {
    $('.rez').text('Valid Domain Name');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="domainForm" action="">
  http://<input type="text" size="10" name="domain_name" id="domain_name" />
  <p class="rez"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: That is some pretty code - thank you! - but as with DGS's suggestion, it doesn't return anything. No matter what I type, the <p> is blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate in real time you can bind a handler to the keyup event of the input like

```
$('#domain_name').on('keyup', function(){
    if(!validateDomain($(this).val())){
       $('.rez').text('invalid domain')
    }else{
       $('.rez').text('valid domain')
    }
});
```

Also put `return true;` at the end of your function so a successful validation will return true

```
function validateDomain(the_domain)
  {  
    // strip off "http://" and/or "www."
    the_domain = the_domain.replace("http://","");
    the_domain = the_domain.replace("www.","");

    var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
    return reg.test(the_domain);
  } // end validateDomain()
```

Would be my suggestion.

Snippet:

```js
$('#domain_name').on('keyup', function() {
  if (!validateDomain($(this).val())) {
    $('.rez').text('invalid domain')
  } else {
    $('.rez').text('valid domain')
  }
});

function validateDomain(the_domain) {
  // strip off "http://" and/or "www."
  the_domain = the_domain.replace("http://", "");
  the_domain = the_domain.replace("www.", "");

  var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
  return reg.test(the_domain);
} // end validateDomain()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="domainForm" action="">
  http://<input type="text" size="10" name="domain_name" id="domain_name">
  <p class="rez"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Great suggestion! Exactly what I was thinking too ... but alas, doesn't work. I created a div called id="testdiv" and then in the keyup function put document.testdiv.innerHTML = "invalid"; ... but nothing happens.

Comment: Had to change a few values, make sure you have included the jQuery library or this solution won't work

Comment: fiddle gives a blank result also?

Comment: Yeah it was highlighting the field. It now displays text in the p

Comment: WOW! The fiddle works great! However, when I put it into my code, it STILL shows up blank! UGH!! I'll have to hack on it outside this thread but *massive* thanks to you for such a speedy/thorough solution!

Comment: Update your question with the code you are using and if this answer helped you make sure to set it as the accepted answer so other people who come with the same question can find an answer